# Filtering images with a search bar

Tags: reactjs, search, react-native

I am trying to create a search bar to filter images that are displayed on `SearchScreen.js`. The user types the name of the image and then then the image is filtered. Every image will have a key name which will allow the user to search for them.

`const listItems = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']` has the list of those keys. I want each one to be atributed for each different image. For example: first image receives key "A". So whenever someone wants to find the first image they search "A" to find them.

This is the full `SearchScreen.js` code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, View, FlatList, Keyboard, Image, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

const listItems = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

function SearchScreen({navigation}) {

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
  <Animatable.View animation='slideInLeft' duration={500} style={styles.container}>
    <View>
      <Icon name={"ios-search"} style={styles.icon}/>
    </View>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
              underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
              placeholder="Procura aqui"
              placeholderTextColor = "black"
              selectionColor="black"
              keyboardType="default"/>
  </Animatable.View>
  <View style={styles.teste}> 
    <Text style={styles.festivais}>Recomendados</Text>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.festivais_lista}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('meo_sw')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/meo_sudoeste.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('vodaf_coura')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/vodafone_coura.png')} style={styles.image} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('superR_superB')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/superbock_superrock.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('nos')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/nos_primavera.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('rock_in_rio')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/rock_in_rio.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('edp_cool_jazz')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/edp_cooljazz.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
  );
}

SearchScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Procurar',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 /Irrelevant
});

export default SearchScreen;
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Use Lodash library to implement this searching.

Comment: I am sorry, I am kind of new to React Native. How do I apply it in this especific case?